# How to set NULL if getting empty value from database? I am getting 500 internal server error

Tags: java, null, resultset, is-empty, isnull

I would like to set the value as null if I am getting an Empty value from the database.

Note: I was getting white space so used the `trimToEmpty()` method.

***Currently**:* Postman shows -> department : ''

```
resultset.setDepartment(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(rs.getString("Department")));
```

Changed to :

```
resultset.setDepartment(StringUtils.trimToEmpty(rs.getString("Department")).isEmpty() ? null : StringUtils.trimToEmpty(rs.getString("Department")));
```

Getting Error: "message": "Internal Server Error"

Comment: Check the server logs to see what the error was.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, I did but logs are not clear enough to catch this error.

Comment: Is there any other way I can check the field value coming as empty from the database and replace it with the NULL. Any example would be great.

Comment: 500 error is any error on the server, which means it could be your have something else...(like a NullPointereException) so while you're trying to solve the empty field,  you might be having some other problem. 

In the logs look for something that looks like a stacktrace

Comment: And if you have access to the server-logs, please __post the full stacktrace from error logs__.  Then we might spot the issue and help you.

Answer (score 0):

You report about Java and database access - so I'm assuming you are somewhere on JDBC or Datasource. You send a query to the database, and the result may contain empty values that you want to treat like null values.

Well, databases distinguish between unknown (NULL) data and known empty data. So either you would have to add restrictions to your database (e.g. alter the columns to be non-nullable). Much smoother might be to treat those values in your code - but be aware to do it consistently across all your code. Central accessor methods may make this task easier.

Here is an example how your code might look like using [String::isBlank()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()):

```
String value = ...
if (value != null && value.isBlank()) {
    value = null;
}
resultset.setDepartment(value);
```

However I am not sure whether the last line would work as intended. I just made it similar to the code you posted before.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that you should check the logs since the issue might just be something else.

Anyway, you can replace

```
StringUtils.trimToEmpty(rs.getString("Department")).isEmpty() ? null : StringUtils.trimToEmpty(rs.getString("Department"))
```

By the more simple

```
StringUtils.stripToNull(rs.getString("Department"))
```

or

```
StringUtils.trimToNull(rs.getString("Department"))
```

If that is what you really want to achieve